# Laravel 5.2 seed specific data array

Tags: database, laravel, migration, seed, faker

I am trying to **seed** my database with some **specific** content to get my application started. I am aware of Faker and how to use it (which I do for my Users). Now I want to fill a table with (alot) of records that are not randomly generated, so not created by Faker.

**For example** I want to have a table with some (lets say 30) clubs so that I can generate a few hundered users who are member of one of those 30 clubs with `$faker->randomElement`.

Is there another way then to type this 30 times?

> ```
>    $club = Club::create(array(
>         'name' => 'FC Barcelona',
>         'number' => '001',
>     ));
> ```

Couldn't find this in the laravel (5.2) docs. Only the Faker is explained.

Thanks

Comment: you could make an array of the values you need and iterate through them.

Comment: @lagbox and how exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is creating one array with clubs and seed them and in UsersDatabaseSeeder you can create in loop as many records you want and assign for each of them random club.

**EDIT**

```
$clubs = [['prop1'=> 'val1',], ['prop1' => 'val2']];
\DB::table('clubs')->insert($clubs);
```

Comment: And how do I seed this array into clubs?

Comment: Yeah.. Seed doesn't run and I get this error.. nothing more  
`[ErrorException] preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Comment: @NicolasVanhecke Sorry for that, I've fixed the code in my answer

Comment: Ah I see now.. This I understand! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Content::create(array(
            'content_title' => 'Swiss Army Man',
            'content_link' => 'www.Youtube.com',
            'description' => 'This movie is .....',
            'content_title' => 'Movie',
            'image_path' =>  'images/m1.jpg',
            'year' => '2014-12-4'
        ));

   Content::create(array(
            'content_title' => 'Me Before You',
            'content_link' => 'www.Youtube.com',
            'description' => 'asdddddd',
            'content_title' => 'Movie',
            'image_path' =>  'images/m2.jpg',
            'year' => '2016-6-4'

        ));
,,, So You can create as many as u want ;)
```